# How to emit type tags when serializing with YamlDotNet?

Tags: c#, serialization, yaml, yamldotnet

If I add `EnsureRoundtrip()` as below, my serialization fails, because I have types without default constructors (which I intend to resolve via custom desrializers):

```
var yaml = new SerializerBuilder()
    .EnsureRoundtrip()
    .Build()
    .Serialize(model);
```

So how can I emit type tags and succeeding in serialization?

Comment: Serialize only process the public object so removing public I think would solve you issue.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I understand. Removing `public` from `model`'s type?

Comment: Are you trying to Serialize or Deserialize?  Serialize to will only look at public variables so you can avoid errors by not making properties public.  When deserializg you can create a public object and then put get;set that does not do anything to temporarily eliminate the errors.